# Automapper and use a alternative key

Tags: c#, automapper

How can I map two objects like

```
 class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child> Childrens { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int AlternativeKey { get; set; }
}
```

Parent1

```
{
    "Id": "1367debe-7d88-41c7-b152-0ff0747e5d4b",
    "Children": [{
            "Id":"8d1377b7-1190-48b1-aa21-53a2eb95837b",
            "AlternativeKey":"13",
            "Name":""
        },
        {
            "Id":"ed3eea42-4ff3-40f0-9b84-7f8c4ae6f603",
            "AlternativeKey":"14",
            "Name":""
        }
        ]
}
```

Parent2

```
{
    "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Children": [{
            "Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "AlternativeKey":"13",
            "Name":"ABC"
        },
        {
            "Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "AlternativeKey":"14",
            "Name":"Foo"
        }
        ]
}
```

And now I  want to merge these with automapper. And the result should be the name from Parent2 in Parent1. My problem is to use AlternativeKey as mapping primary key instead of Id.

Expected result

```
{
    "Id": "1367debe-7d88-41c7-b152-0ff0747e5d4b",
    "Children": [{
            "Id":"8d1377b7-1190-48b1-aa21-53a2eb95837b",
            "AlternativeKey":"13",
            "Name":"ABC"
        },
        {
            "Id":"ed3eea42-4ff3-40f0-9b84-7f8c4ae6f603",
            "AlternativeKey":"14",
            "Name":"Foo"
        }
        ]
}
```